# Record practice with persistent

Tags: haskell

I am starting to use Persistent, and I have a question. How should we create records with Persistent? For example:

```
share [..] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name Text
    age  Text
|]
-- or
share [..] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    personName Text
    personAge  Text
|]
```

In this case, is it good practice to "namespace" the fields of the record?

Comment: no - `persistLowerCase` will prepend the `person...` for you ;) - so you will end up with a `Person` and getters `personName`, `personAge` and `personId` anyway ;)

Comment: Ohh, cool then, thanks

Comment: but note that you still have to give the types - so you should do `Person ... name Text ... age Int` or something similar

Comment: Oh Yeah, I forgot to put on the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer - I hope you don't mind

---

you don't have to prepend the `person` - *persistent*  will do this for you

so you will end up with a `Person` type and getters `personName`, `personAge` and `personId` when you use something like

```
mkPersist mySqlSettings [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name Text
    age  Int
|]
```

there is a rather good [documentation](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) explaining this in detail on the  online yesod-book.

---

PS: of course `age Text` is ok too - but it seems a bit odd